# "Silent" Backgrounding a Process

Tags: unix, background-process

I have added a `git pull &` to my bashrc to keep a particular project always up to date!

However this means every time I open a terminal I get a message like

```
[17]+ Running git pull
```

And a few seconds later

```
[17] Done
```

Is there a way to stop this output? I'm already sending all output to dev null so the full command is
`git pull >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The messages on screen are the result of **backgrounding** the job, *not* the job itself.

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec &> /dev/null
git pull
```

In this variant, the process backgrounding the job is a script that *already* redirects all output.

Of course, such a command should really go in your bash_login, or in your .profile, not in .bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *at(1)* or even *batch(1)* to start your command:

```
echo git pull | at now 2>/dev/null
```

This way it would also not receive a SIGHUP if you log out immediately.
The `2>/dev/null` prevents the message `job 1334584295.a at Mon Apr 16 15:51:35 2012` to be written by the *at* command.

You may have to add your user name to `/usr/lib/cron/at.allow` (location of this file may differ with our flavour of UNIX/Linux).

Answer (score 0):

Use a subshell and mute STDOUT and STDERR:

```
(&>/dev/null git pull &)
```

Answer (score 0):

use nohup:

```
nohup git pull &
```

Answer (score -1):

I found that using a subshell silences the backgrounding of the job:

```
(git pull &)
```